# Looping over unknown query result properties

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In a CodeIgniter model class, given a query that returns unknown table columns,

```
$sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDatabase' AND TABLE_NAME = 'assets';";
return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
```

And where the CodeIgniter docs give the example of looping over a query result with known object properties:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->title;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->body;
}
```

I need to do the same thing, using a foreach, but I don't necessarily know the names of the properties (the table column names), or even how many (as in how many table columns) there are.

It would be nice if I could just loop using a foreach, as in

```
foreach($result as $row){
    for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++){
        echo $row[$i] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

...but this produces errors, `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [COLUMN_NAME] => as_id
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [COLUMN_NAME] => as_type
    )...(etc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually possible, [using a regular `foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), to iterate over an object the same way you would iterate over an array to read both the key and value.

Given your `$query->result()` array, you can iterate it with a nested `foreach`:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
  // The object can be looped with foreach
  // using $property as the prop name and $value as the value
  foreach ($row as $property => $value) {
    echo "Property: $property, Value: $value\n";
  }
}
```

Now however, you are executing a known query against `information_schema.columns`, and the only result column returned by that query is `COLUMN_NAME`. So iterating the `result()` and reading the `COLUMN_NAME` property will actually give you the values you need:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
  // The only column returned is COLUMN_NAME
  echo $row->COLUMN_NAME;
}
```

In other words, although the query will return an unknown number of string values *representing* MySQL table column names, the query itself does *not* return an unknown set of columns - it always returns *one* column called `COLUMN_NAME`; in and of itself, it is not dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreach to traverse the array now in first foreach each record is accessed and in other foreach you traverse in side the array and get the value

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   foreach($row as $column=> $value)
   {
      echo "column name is $column and its value is $value </br>";
   }
}
```

Hope you get the concept for it

Comment: How could I have missed that? Thanks, it also works.